# How do I ignore the country code on telephone number (with and without the +) with regex

Tags: java, regex

So I'm building an app with a phone number registration. In an OTP page, I would like to display the phone number (input by user) with a separator with the following rules : (I'm from Indonesia so my country code is +62)

```
+628101234567890 -> +62810-1234-5678-90
628101234567890  -> 62810-1234-5678-90
08101234567890   -> 0810-1234-5678-90
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks before

EDIT: the phone number has a range from 9-14 digits

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**String::replaceAll**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) with a regex [`^(.*)(....)(....)(..)$`](https://regex101.com/r/0wckag/1/) which matches multiple groups, for example :

```
String[] phones = {"+628101234567890", "628101234567890", "08101234567890"};
for (String phone : phones) {
    System.out.println(phone.replaceAll("(.*)(....)(....)(..)", "$1-$2-$3-$4"));
}
```

Outputs

```
+62810-1234-5678-90
62810-1234-5678-90
0810-1234-5678-90
```

You can even use this regex [`(.*)(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/kIveSM/1)

**details**

I would like to explain the regex from the end instead from the start :

- `(..)` last group which match 2 character
- `(....)(....)` two groups with 4 characters
- `(.*)` and the rest of the characters

Comment: In this case a lazy dot quantifier performs better `(.+?)`

Comment: @revo you mean `(.*?)` no?

Comment: You don't need star. In a lazy way it matches zero-length positions at each single step. For the sake of performance this `^.*$(?<=^(.*)(....)(....)(..))` is much better which follows the way you explained. From end to the beginning.

Comment: @YCF_L thanks a lot for the answer, this works a lot in this case, but I have an additional problem where the phone number have a range from 9-14 digits
`from 0810-1234-56 to 0810-1234-5678-90`

Comment: @AlvinWidjaja what did you mean I don't get you?

Answer (score 1):

```
String formatTelephone(String tel) {
    return tel.replace(" ", "")
              .replaceFirst("^(0|\\+?62)(\\d{3})(\\d{4})(\\d4)",
                             "$1$2-$3-$4-")
              .replaceFirst("^(0|\\+?62)(\\d{3})(\\d{4})",
                             "$1$2-$3-");
}
```

This will take from the start `^` the alternative 0 +62 and 62 followed by digits groups. The remaining is not substituted. And the original tel is returned, say for foreign numbers.

As extra precaution spaces are removed in advance.

```
^ : start of string, so 99962999 will not match ^62
\\d : digit
X? : optional X
X{3} : XXX
(X|Y|Z) : either X, Y or Z
```

---

***Added a second replaceFirst***

To tackle both 0810-1234-56 to 0810-1234-5678-90 the first replaceFirst only works on the longer number. If replaced, the additional `-` causes the second replaceFirst not to work (returning the just replaced string).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, this works a lot in this case, but I have an additional problem where the phone number have a range from 9-14 digits from 0810-1234-56 to 0810-1234-5678-90

Comment: In that case it seems the simplest to just do two regex replaces, see extended answer. If a regex does not match, the passed string is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at this phone library form google https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber (if you are coding in any of the supported languages). It can help you parse and format numbers without writing your own regex